# Exercise $17$, Section $3.B$ - Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Exercise: Suppose $V$ and $W$ are both finite-dimensional. Prove that there exists an
injective linear map from $V$ to $W$ if and only if $\dim V \le \dim W$.

Proof: Suppose there exists a linear map $T : V\to W$ that is injective. Then we have that $\dim V \le \dim W$ as if $\dim V > \dim W$ then $T$ can't be injective.(Using a theorem that if $\dim V > \dim W$, then $T$ can't be injective).

In the other direction, suppose that $\dim V \le \dim W$. Define $T : V\to W$ by $Tv_i=w_i$ for $i=1,\dots,\dim V$. Where $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1,\dots,w_m$ is a basis of $W$. To show that this linear map is injective, suppose there exist $u, v\in V$ such that $Tu=Tv$. Then we have that $T(u)-T(v)=0$. Because $V$ is finite dimensional, we can write $u$ and $v$ in terms of the basis of $V$.
Let $u=a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n$ and $v=c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n$. Then $T(u-v)=T(a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n - c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n)$. By definition of $T$ we have that $T(u-v)=(a_1-c_1)w_1+\dots+(a_n-c_n)w_n=0$. Because $w_1,\dots,w_m$ is linearly independent, we have that $a_j=c_j$. Hence, $u=v$ and $T$ is injective.

Is the proof correct?

Edit: When defining the linear map in the second part of the argument, I used the theorem that there exist a unique linear map that can take on any value we want on the basis of a finite dimensional vector space. So the map defined in the second part is indeed a linear map defined from $V \to W$.

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: Yes, however with vector spaces and linear maps between them, for determining injectivity, it suffices just to check 
$$
T(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{0} \quad \implies \quad \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}
$$

Comment: @SammyBlack Yeah I thought of using that theorem as soon as I posted the question. It would be a simple check as if $Tv=0$ would imply that $a_1T(v_1)+\dots+a_nT(v_n)=0$. From which it would follow that $v=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

How about using the *first isomorphism theorem* for vector spaces?

The image $T(V)$ is isomorphic to $V/\rm{ker}(T)=V/\{0\}\cong V$. (Since an injection corresponds to zero kernel.)

So $V$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $W$.

(The converse you seem to have done.)

Comment: Thanks for that. I’m not familiar with isomorphisms of vector spaces that much. I do recognise the notation in your answer as the notation for quotient groups but I haven’t yet learnt a lot of group theory either. But sounds like an interesting way to prove it!

Comment: Yes.  It's a good theorem to know.   The one for vector spaces is completely analogous to the one for groups.  There's also a second and third (I think).